# Unregistering from the JQUERY Keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove the keydown event that I have created using the following code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    alert("Key Down");
});
```

when I am using the following code:

```
$(document).off('keydown');
```

it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off'
```

can someone point me to the correct way to un-register from the `keydown` event?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unbind all `keydown` handlers from `document`:

```
$(document).unbind('keydown');
```

Or to make sure you only unbind that specific handler:

```
function myHandler(e) {
    alert("Key Down");
}

$(document).keydown(myHandler);
// later
$(document).unbind('keydown', myHandler);
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind

Comment: As of jquery 1.7 the unbind function is obsolete. It's better use the off function

Comment: But we know that the OP is not using a version of jQuery which supports `.off()`.

Comment: yes he's probably using an old version. Then unbind is the only choice

Comment: Well yes, that's why I suggested it.